# Is it legal to deploy a microservices based project using AGPL with some proprietary services when the AGPL code is not modified?

Tags: docker, agpl

My company wants to use a project composed by many microservice that are AGPL licensed. We're not worried by about distributing the AGPL parts in open source of course, but some of our services remains proprietary. (I mean, the code was written by us and we just want to connect our backend services to the AGPL project for data analysis)

By example, we have a service A which call a service B. Normally the open source projet do this:

```
A --> B
```

But in order to fetch data from A without making any modification on A, we have a proxy service C which acts as B. From C we code anything in order to use other proprietary services.

So the AGPL calls our service C instead of B but we can also redirect the request to B after all.

```
A --> C or A --> C --> B

or even A --> C --> ? (other services)
              |---> B
```

Of course we need to modify the docker-compose file to connect C or we need to deploy C with exactly the same configuration as B.

Honestly I think C is illegal here because C is on the same network and the user doesn't know anything from it, it acts like a black box that allows us to use our services.

What should I do ? Making the entired project open source ? Or do you think C is legal here ?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: I recommend you read the questions and answers here related to [AGPL and use of proxies](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/search?q=agpl+proxy) and you should also check if the parts of your service are closely tied together or a [Mere Aggregation](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#MereAggregation). If anything is open after that, then please revise your question to be specific in what you need.

Comment: Thank you, if I understand I think I can proxify a service in the stack using proprietary code here. It should be ok.
I learn that AGPL force you to share the source code to the user of the application. In our case, it means sharing to our customer because it's a private SaaS.

After some discussion, sharing the code with our customer is not a problem for us, so the AGPL is no longer an issue I guess.

But it's still interesting to keep some part of our code without AGPL I think.